Changing order of integration for triple integral of $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 25$, bounded by two planes.
I’m trying to solve a problem involving calculating the volume of a solid contained in $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 25$, and bounded by the planes $z=-4$ and $z=3$.
We can see the solid:

I know it is fairly straightforward to calculate the volume by converting to cylindrical coords.
I am wondering about representing the volume in rectangular coords, as a single integral, using different orders of integration.
I can see how I might do so with $dxdydz$ or $dydxdz$, but are there any other orders that might work? (e.g., $dzdydx$ or $dydzdx$)
Instinctually I don’t believe so, as we can’t draw a line in the direction of the $z$-axis, while remaining within the solid for all points. Is this along the right lines of thinking?

The volume of $x^2+y^2=z^2+25, $ $z_{k-1}\le z\le z_k$ is approximately equal $\pi(z^2+25)(z_k-z_{k-1}).$ So $$V=\int\limits_{-4}^3\pi(z^2+25),dz $$ You can replace $\pi(z^2+25)$ by a double integral with respect to $x,y,$ but this will make things complicated. In general if a solid is located between $z_1\le z\le z_2$ and the area of its intersection with the horizontal plane  $z=z_0$ is equal $A(z)$ then $$V=\int\limits_{z_1}^{z_2}A(z),dz$$

When the intersection of a line and the region of integration is not a single segment in the region, we need to split into multiple integrals. If the number of intersections depends on other variables, those other variables must also split at those boundaries.
So for the order $dz\, dy\, dx$, it's possible but ugly. We see that the values of $z$ in the solid are
$$ \begin{array}{rl} -4 \leq z \leq 3 &\textrm{ if } x^2+y^2 \leq 25 \\
-4 \leq z \leq -\sqrt{x^2+y^2-25} \textrm{ or } \sqrt{x^2+y^2-25} \leq z \leq 3 &\textrm{ if } 25 < x^2+y^2 \leq 34 \\
-4 \leq z \leq -\sqrt{x^2+y^2-25} &\textrm{ if } 34 < x^2+y^2 \leq 41
\end{array} $$
and the volume is
$$ V = V_1 + V_2 + V_3 + V_4 $$
where
$$ \begin{align*} V_1 &= \iint_{x^2 + y^2 \leq 25} \int_{-4}^3 dz\, dy\, dx \\
V_2 &= \iint_{25 < x^2+y^2 \leq 34} \int_{-4}^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2-25}} dz\, dy\, dx \\
V_3 &= \iint_{25 < x^2+y^2 \leq 34} \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-25}}^3 dz\, dy\, dx
\\
V_4 &= \iint_{34 < x^2+y^2 \leq 41} \int_{-4}^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2-25}} dz\, dy\, dx
\end{align*} $$
$V_1$ is a simple circular cylinder, so we can either use the familiar $V = \pi r^2 h$ formula or write it as
$$ V_1 = \int_{-5}^5 \int_{-\sqrt{25-x^2}}^{\sqrt{25-x^2}} \int_{-4}^3 dz\, dy\, dz $$
At least we can combine $V_2$ and $V_4$. Then the sum of three integrals is the same as what we would get if we had first divided the solid into the cylinder with volume $V_1$ and the remaining two regions below and above the $z=0$ plane.
$$ V_2 + V_4 = \iint_{25 < x^2+y^2 \leq 41} \int_{-4}^{-\sqrt{x^2+y^2-25}} dz\, dy\, dx $$
Next, lines with constant $x$ intersect the annular region $25 < x^2 + y^2 \leq 34$ where
$$ \begin{array}{rl} -\sqrt{34-x^2} \leq y \leq \sqrt{34-x^2} &\mathrm{ if } -\sqrt{34} \leq x \leq -5 \mathrm{ or } 5 \leq x \leq \sqrt{34} \\
-\sqrt{34-x^2} \leq y \leq -\sqrt{25-x^2} \mathrm{ or } \sqrt{25-x^2} \leq y \leq 
\end{array} $$
Therefore $V_3 = V_{3a} + V_{3b} + V_{3c} + V_{3d}$, where
$$ \begin{align*} V_{3a} &= \int_{-\sqrt{34}}^{-5} \int_{-\sqrt{34-x^2}}^{\sqrt{34-x^2}} \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-25}}^3 dz\, dy\, dx \\
V_{3b} &= \int_{-5}^5 \int_{-\sqrt{34-x^2}}^{-\sqrt{25-x^2}} \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-25}}^3 dz\, dy\, dx \\
V_{3c} &= \int_{-5}^5 \int_{\sqrt{25-x^2}}^{\sqrt{34-x^2}} \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-25}}^3 dz\, dy\, dx \\
V_{3d} &= \int_5^{\sqrt{34}} \int_{-\sqrt{34-x^2}}^{\sqrt{34-x^2}} \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-25}}^3 dz\, dy\, dx
\end{align*} $$
We can see $V_{3a} = V_{3d}$ and $V_{3b} = V_{3c}$ by geometric symmetry or by sign-flipping variable substitutions.
Similarly, $V_2+V_4 = V_{4a}+V_{4b}+V_{4c}+V_{4d}$ where
$$ \begin{align*} V_{4a} &= \int_{-\sqrt{41}}^{-5} \int_{-\sqrt{41-x^2}}^{\sqrt{41-x^2}} \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-25}}^3 dz\, dy\, dx \\
V_{4b} &= \int_{-5}^5 \int_{-\sqrt{41-x^2}}^{-\sqrt{25-x^2}} \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-25}}^3 dz\, dy\, dx \\
V_{4c} &= \int_{-5}^5 \int_{\sqrt{25-x^2}}^{\sqrt{41-x^2}} \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-25}}^3 dz\, dy\, dx \\
V_{4d} &= \int_5^{\sqrt{41}} \int_{-\sqrt{41-x^2}}^{\sqrt{41-x^2}} \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-25}}^3 dz\, dy\, dx
\end{align*} $$
and $V_{4a} = V_{4d}, V_{4b}=V_{4c}$.
This is a terrible order of integration for this particular region, but this is the sort of technique that works in general for any shape and any order of coordinates. The coordinates don't even need to be Cartesian; the same principles apply to subdividing regions in cylindrical coordinates, spherical, or any other parameterization, just keeping the Jacobian term (such as the $r$ in $dx\, dy\, dz = r\, dz\, dr\, d\theta$ or the $\rho^2 \sin \phi$ in $dx\, dy\, dz = \rho^2 \sin \phi\, d\rho\, d\phi\, d\theta$) in each region's integral.
